# Looking for mysql query to get the column value other than except same row

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking for mysql query to get the column value other than except same row

```
USER  VALUE   
----------
Mike  15        
Bob   16        
Bunny 60        
Mike  20
Bob   15
Bunny 20
```

Output Should be in below format:

### USER   VALUE

```
Mike   16
Mike   60       
Bob    20
Bob    60       
Bunny  15
Bunny  16
```

Comment: Can you have duplicates?  How should they be handled?

Answer (score 1):

Very strange request.  Here is one method that should work for the data in your question:

```
select t.user, group_concat(t2.value order by t2.value)
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.user <> t.user
group by t.user;
```

Comment: For completness you should use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.VALUE ORDER BY t2.VALUE)` [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/386bc4/8/0). In current form you will get `Mike  16,60,16,60`

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Duplicates introduce other issues, that the OP doesn't explain.

Comment: But ordering can be handled in current form. This is rather clear from example OP provided

Comment: Thanks Gordon and Lad2025. Query works but when I add more complexity like                                                                                                     Mike  15        
Bob   16        
Bunny 60        
Mike  20
Bob    15
Bunny 20
 then sql works differently

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I corrected the question and output format

Comment: @Vikas . . . If you have duplicate values, you should ask another question.  You can reference this one, but it is very important that you describe exactly what should happen with the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (USER VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,VALUE   INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(user,value));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
('Mike',15),
('Bob',16),
('Bunny', 60),
('Mike',  20),
('Bob',   15),
('Bunny', 20); 

 SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
   FROM (SELECT x.user,y.value FROM my_table x,my_table y) a 
   LEFT 
   JOIN my_table b 
     ON b.user = a.user 
    AND b.value = a.value 
  WHERE b.user IS NULL;
+-------+-------+
| user  | value |
+-------+-------+
| Bunny |    15 |
| Bunny |    16 |
| Mike  |    16 |
| Bob   |    20 |
| Bob   |    60 |
| Mike  |    60 |
+-------+-------+
```